# How to select last three month all dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I want to select all last 3 month dates from the table in SQL Server.

Data is like this:

```
Sunday 20-05-2012
Sunday 27-05-2012
Sunday 10-06-2012
Sunday 24-06-2012
Sunday 08-07-2012
Sunday 22-07-2012
Sunday 12-08-2012
Sunday 19-08-2012
Sunday 09-09-2012
Sunday 16-09-2012
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: are you looking to return only Sunday dates?  or all dates?

Answer (score 4):

Saving date column as varchar with day of week - bad idea. You can't write faster query, because you must convert all of time your field for using it in where clause. Also your query can't use indexes of date_column and each query will be use scan index.

With datetime column, query should be:

```
select date_column
  from table_name
 where date_column between dateadd(m, -3, getdate()) and getdate()
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Comment: What kind of type your date_column? varchar?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this query:

```
select date_column from table_name
where datepart(m,date_column) > datepart(m,getdate())-3 and datepart(yy,date_column) >= datepart(yy,getdate())
```

Comment: Thank for repaly I get error massage like "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string."

Comment: I suppose your date column is stroing string data type instead of date data type. So you will have to use either string to date conversion or string manipulations. Try this query that uses string manipulations: select temp_date from temp_dates
where cast(substring(substring(temp_date,charindex('y',temp_date)+2,10),4,2) as int) > datepart(m,getdate())-3
and cast(substring(substring(temp_date,charindex('y',temp_date)+2,10),7,4) as int) >= datepart(yy,getdate())

Comment: That query would be like a turtle, because type of field in user1661868 table are wrong.